# How to parse JSON data without array string?

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I am trying to parse data from JSON but my JSON data is an array without a string name. Here is an example:

```
[
{
"$id": "1",
"ClubVideoId": 1027,
"ClubId": 1,
"Title": "Brian Interview",
"ThumbURL": "url",
"VideoURL": "urll",
"DateAdded": "2014-03-25 00:00"
},
{
"$id": "2",
"ClubVideoId": 1028,
"ClubId": 1,
"Title": "Chase Interview",
"ThumbURL": "url",
"VideoURL": "urll",
"DateAdded": "2014-03-25 00:00"
},
```

I can seem to pass an Array without a string. Here is my code:

```
public void handleBlogResponse() {
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    if (mVideoData == null) {
        updateDisplayForError();
    }
    else {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonPosts = mVideoData.getJSONArray("");
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> clubVideos = 
                    new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonPosts.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject post = jsonPosts.getJSONObject(i);
                String thumburl = post.getString(KEY_THUMBURL);
                thumburl = Html.fromHtml(thumburl).toString();
                String dateurl = post.getString(KEY_DATEADDED);
                dateurl = Html.fromHtml(dateurl).toString();

                HashMap<String, String> blogPost = new HashMap<String, String>();
                blogPost.put(KEY_THUMBURL, thumburl);
                blogPost.put(KEY_DATEADDED, dateurl);

                clubVideos.add(blogPost);
            }

            String[] keys = {KEY_THUMBURL, KEY_DATEADDED};
            int[] ids = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, clubVideos,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, keys, ids);
            setListAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught!!", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Any Suggestions?

Here is where I'm pulling my json:

```
@Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
    int responseCode = -1;  
    JSONObject jsonResponse = null;

    try {   
        URL blogFeedUrl = new URL("http://x.com/api/Club/Getx/1/?count=" + NUMBER_OF_POSTS);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) blogFeedUrl.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();
            char[] charArray = new char[contentLength];
            reader.read(charArray);
            String responseData = new String(charArray);

            jsonResponse = new JSONObject(responseData);
        }
        else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Unsuccessful HTTP Response Code: " + responseCode);
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Code: " + responseCode);
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        logException(e);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        logException(e);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        logException(e);
    }

    return jsonResponse;
}'
```

Comment: `JSONArray jsonPosts = mVideoData.getJSONArray("");` is wrong. what is `mVideoData`?

Comment: **"...my JSON data is an array without a string name."** : JSON arrays don't have 'names' - it's only JSON objects which have name/value pairs. An array is simply a 'value' enclosed in `[...]`. For reference this pretty much explains JSON syntax / formatting in one page http://www.json.org/

Comment: the .getJSONArray("") is there because the JSON data doesn't have an array name

Comment: @user3529614 there is no need for that. You can simply loop through the jsonarray. its a json array that you ahve

Comment: how do I loop through a jsonarray?

Comment: @user3529614 why are you editing my post?? It will be rejected a invalid any way.

Answer (score 1):

> how do I loop through a jsonarray?

```
JSONArray jr = new JSONArray("json string");
for(int i=0;i<jr.length();i++)
{
   JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) jr.get(i);
   String id =jb.getString("$id");
   String clubvid = jb.getString("ClubVideoId");
   ...// similarly others
}
```

As squonk suggested

```
[  // json array node
{   // json object node 
"$id": "1",
```

Edit:

The below should be in a thread

```
@Override 
protected String doInBackground(Object... arg0)
{
String _response=null;
try
{
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://sql.gamedayxtra.com/api/Club/GetClubVideos/1");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
_response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
}catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return _response;

}
```

In onPostExecute

```
@Override 
protected void onPostExecute(String _response)
JSONArray jr = new JSONArray("_response");
for(int i=0;i<jr.length();i++)
{
   JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) jr.get(i);
   String id =jb.getString("$id");
   String clubvid = jb.getString("ClubVideoId");
   ...// similarly others
}
```

Comment: ok but the "json string" for the new JSONArray doesnt exist. The json data is just a square bracket with no array name.

Comment: @user3529614 where is your json. forget the name. there is no need for that. json string is your json

Comment: my json is "$id": "1",
"ClubVideoId": 1027,
"ClubId": 1,
"Title": "Brian Interview",
"ThumbURL": "url",
"VideoURL": "urll",
"DateAdded": "2014-03-25 00:00"

Comment: @user3529614 nope you forgot `[{`. these are key value pairs `"$id": "1",` where $id is the key and the value is 1

Comment: Do i add the entire json data into the array string? Including the [{

Comment: @user3529614 first tell me where do you get json from?? and what is `mVideoData`?

Comment: and mVideoData is a protected JSONObject

Comment: so your downloading the json . i see no json object there by that name

Comment: @user3529614 post the code where you download the json

Comment: @user3529614 that is separate question. If this answer helps accept the same by clicking on the tick next to it. Post a new question and i will be happy to answer. Comment section is not for asking or posting codes